Unexpected language error when using Mastodon API on Dart
I am creating a function that would search a query in available statuses' contents. However, the result does not upload and the following exception is thrown in the terminal:
flutter: error!!! CheckedFromJsonException
flutter: Could not create `_$_Status`.
flutter: There is a problem with "language".
flutter: `sco` is not one of the supported values: aa, ab, ae, af ... 
// (just a list of the instance's languages)

I cannot wrap my head around this.
If this is a mismatch of language encoding standards with some other instance, it sure has caught me off guard. I expected the function to load data as intended.
Future<void> fetchPage(int pageKey) async {
    try {
      final response = await mstdn.v2.search.searchContents(
          query: widget.query, type: SearchContentType.statuses);
      print(response.data);
      List responseList = response.data.statuses as List;
      print(responseList);
      final postList = responseList
          .map((data) => FeedStatusWidget(
                statusId: data.id,
              ))
          .toList();
      print(postList);
      final isLastPage = postList.length < postsPerRequest;
      if (isLastPage) {
        pagingController.appendLastPage(postList);
        debugPrint('Last page');
      } else {
        final nextPageKey = pageKey + 1;
        pagingController.appendPage(postList, nextPageKey);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      debugPrint(
          'error!!! $error'); //TODO figure out why the `sco` of all things holy...
      pagingController.error = error;
    }
  }

